# How do I print the Pi symbol using the curses module

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

I am trying to print the symbol pi to the terminal using curses.ACS_PI, but whenever I do so, it returns an error:

```
>>> import curses
>>> print(curses.ACS_PI)
AttributeError: module 'curses' has no attribute 'ACS_PI'
```

How do I get it to print pi to the terminal screen?

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html): "Note: These are available only after initscr() has been called."

Answer (score 1):

The ACS_* ones are only added to the curses module's dictionary after initscr() is called.

```
>>> import curses
>>> curses.initscr()
>>> print(curses.ACS_PI)
>>> 4194427
```